# Reformat column data in R

Tags: r, format

I need to remove all rows where same user_id made another engagement within 30 minutes from the earlier engagements for every set of engagements only if status is not 3. how can i delete such engagements in R.please help me
Here is sample dataset
[sampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bde7q.png)

Comment: Could you add your sample data in the question (in a convnenient copy/paste form) and, also, the expected output?

Comment: Please edit your question by pasting in the results of `dput(head(your_data))` so we can use the data directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you a data frame as shown, you can use dplyr and do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% filter(!(status != 3 & as.numeric(difftime(date_time, lag(date_time), units = 'mins')) <= 30))
```

You are grouping by user_id, so you compute time differences only for engagements of a given user, you are then filtering any status != 3 that has a time difference with the 'lag' engagement of less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Gopala, i have got what i desired. Cheers!